# Why is Calculating with the Cosine function so much faster than with the Secant Trig function?

Tags: matlab, octave, trigonometry

Why is Calculating with the Cosine function so much more faster than with the Secant Trig function?
Is There a way to speed up the secant function?

When calculating using the cosine and secant trig functions the time it takes vary a lot.

```
Cosine = finally Done-elapsed time -36.7544sec- or -0.6126mins- or -0.0102hours- 
Secant = finally Done-elapsed time -43.2231sec- or -0.7204mins- or -0.0120hours-
```

The code I use to test this is below.  I just rem'd out the secant or cosine line to test the speed of each one I wanted.

```
clear all, clc,tic

num_of_values=60000; %number of values to use
a1_dataset =linspace(0,10000,num_of_values)';% 
a1_idx = randi (numel (a1_dataset), num_of_values, 1);
a1=a1_dataset (a1_idx);

a2_dataset =linspace(0,.8,num_of_values)';% 
a2_idx = randi (numel (a2_dataset), num_of_values, 1);
a2=a2_dataset (a2_idx);

a3_dataset =linspace(-360,360,num_of_values)';% 
a3_idx = randi (numel (a3_dataset), num_of_values, 1);
a3=a3_dataset (a3_idx);

array1=[a1,a2,a3];
t_rebuilt=linspace(0,16000,16000);
sig_comb=zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));
for rr=1:1:length(array1) 

    sig_comb=sig_comb+array1(rr,2)*cos (((array1(rr,1))*t_rebuilt)+array1(rr, 3));  %test using cosine
    %sig_comb=sig_comb+array1(rr,2)*sec (((array1(rr,1))*t_rebuilt)+array1(rr, 3)); %test using secant

end

fprintf('\nfinally Done-elapsed time -%4.4fsec- or -%4.4fmins- or -%4.4fhours-\n',toc,toc/60,toc/3600);
```

PS:  I'm using Octave 3.8.1 Linux

Comment: I can't give an authoritative answer, but I would guess that the secant calls cosine internally and then performs a division. It may also have extra code in place to check for and handle the divide-by-zero cases. How does the code perform if you switch it to divide by cosine?

Comment: @Katie: For Octave this is true, see `edit sec`. It's using `1/cos`

Comment: @Daniel why would this slow secant down so much? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @RickT: For future questions, please only post relevant parts of your code. Especially calls like `clf` and the last line are unrelated to this issue.

Comment: @Daniel ok I took them out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octave does not have a native implementation of `sec`, it uses `cos` to do so. Check `edit sec.m` for details.

The difference is caused by

- function calls of `nargin` in `sec`
- function call overhead for `sec`
- dividing the values

To get rid of the first two factors, use `1./cos(x)` instead of `sec(x)`. To get exactly the same speed, a native implementation of `sec` would be required.